# Center a DataGridTextColumn leads to strange style

Tags: wpf

I'm centering some DataGridTextColumns using this style:

```
        <Style x:Key="CenteredCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
```

This works, but it has the effect that when I click one line in my DataGrid, not the full row is highlighted. In any column that is centered using above style, the blue highlighting-background has a white space to the left and right.

What am I doing wrong or is that as supposed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property:

```
<Style x:Key="CenteredCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```